# How to compile AIDL files using meson?

Tags: meson-build

Here are 2 aidl files.

`src/com/rom1v/example/Service.aidl`:

```
package com.rom1v.example;
interface Service {
    void doSomething();
}
```

`src/another/package/Other.aidl`:

```
package another.package;
interface Other {
    int get();
}
```

I would like to compile them using meson, so I started a `build.meson`:

```
project('example', 'java')

aidl = [
    'src/com/rom1v/example/Service.aidl',
    'src/another/package/Other.aidl',
]
```

From these sources, I want to generate:

- `MYBUILDDIR/gen/com/rom1v/example/Service.java`
- `MYBUILDDIR/gen/another/package/Other.java`

To generate them manually, I use these commands:

```
aidl -ogen src/com/rom1v/example/Service.aidl
aidl -ogen src/another/package/Other.aidl
```

How to do the same using Meson?

I guess [generator](http://mesonbuild.com/Generating-sources.html#using-generator) is what I want, but I can't figure out what `output` value to use (it does not accept pathes, and [only supports](http://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#generator) `@PLAINNAME@` and `@BASENAME@` as substitutions).

```
aidl_compiler = find_program('aidl')
gen = generator(aidl_compiler, output: ???, arguments: ['-ogen', '@INPUT@'])
```

Comment: Output would probably be '@BASENAME@.java'

Comment: Also feel free to open an issue against Meson to just get this support built in.